# How to get the selected menu item from the selection event for a paper-menu-button

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm listening to the `paper-menu-button` selection through the `on-core-select` event.

```
  <paper-menu-button icon="menu" on-core-select="{{ selectedItem }}">
      <paper-item label="item 1"></paper-item>
      <paper-item label="item 2"></paper-item>
  </paper-menu-button>
```

In the Dart side:

```
  void selectedItem(event, detail, target) {
    print('SELECTED ${detail}');
  }
```

How can I get the selected item?

I've tried through the `detail` parameter but looks like an "empty" object (inspected through reflections and there are no relevant fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
print(detail['isSelected']); // ignore when false
print(item['detail'].label);
```

The debugger in WebStorm shows the items of an JavaScript object which is a nice feature.

Comment: I was trying through detail.item field. I think should be better to expose it as Dart object.

Comment: Btw you can access the item without 'casting', for example: var label = detail['item'].label;

Comment: Great. I tried `detail['item']['label']` without success ;-)